# WIX Writing user data into config file

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I would like to ask a WiX installer question. I created a working installer that does many things already. I still need to ask the user for some specific information (the GUI is already done), and write it into a config file.

From this snippet, I think I could use the `INSTALLFOLDER` global variable.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="IISROOT" Name='WebDir'>
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="IVRDesigner">
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This is the part, when I want to use that. This code is taken from a tutorial, should work well, if the source tag is filled properly. The `..\src\Web.config` is just a dummy, so the code can compile. The default installed path for the `web.config` file will be `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder`, but the user can change this during the installation.

The question is: how could I use the global variable here, or what kind of solution, do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

```
<Component Id="ConfigureWebConfig" Guid="*">
    <File Id="Web.config" Name="MyConfigfile" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" 
          Source="..\src\Web.config" />
    <util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetConnStr" Action="setValue" 
         Permanent="yes" File="[#Web.config]"
         ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='GeoIVRDesignerEntities'[\]]" Name="connectionString"
         Value="data source=[DBSERVER];" />
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the Product tag I would add the properties that I want to be able to change in the config file like this:

```
<Property Id="BUILDRAN" Value="INSTALLER"/>
<Property Id="EMAIL_RECEIPIANT" Value="thisisnotme@notthere.com" />
```

Create the Fragment for the Directory Structure

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" >
      <Directory Id="BasicDir" Name="Dev_Home">
        <Directory Id="BasicDirSuite" Name="TEST">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DesignPatterns" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Declare another Fragment for the transformation of the config file

```
<util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetBuildRan" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[#App.config]"
     ElementPath="/configuration/applicationSettings/MyApp.Properties.Settings/setting[\[]@name='BuildRan'[\]]/value"
     Value="[BUILDRAN]" />

<util:XmlFile Id="AppConfigSetEmail" Action="setValue" Permanent="yes" File="[#App.config]"
    ElementPath="/configuration/applicationSettings/MyApp.Properties.Settings/setting[\[]@name='TestValue'[\]]/value"
    Value="[EMAIL_RECEIPIANT]" />
```

If you want you can create your own custom dialog to let the End user enter values for the properties [BUILDRAN] && [EMAIL_RECEIPIANT], or you could use the command line and set the properties with parameters

```
msiexec /i My.msi BUILDRAN=SuperDebug EMAIL_RECEIPIANT=you@home.com
```